# Which cities in Vietnam have a Chinese embassy or consulate where I can apply for a visa?

Tags: visas, china, vietnam, embassies, consulates

As usual there are lots of fake sites when trying to Google for current facts about embassies and consulates.

I want to know what my options are for where to apply for my Chinese visa in Vietnam.

I might assume that there would be an embassy in Hanoi and a consulate in Ho Chi Minh, but assumptions are often wrong.

Comment: Incidentally, I just release today this open database of embassies/consulates: http://datahub.io/dataset/embassies-and-consulates not very easy to browse but the info should be inside the CSV file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a community wiki to add to if there are more than these two:

**Embassy** in **Hanoi**, as expected:

- 46 Hoang Dieu Rd, ☎ +84 4 3845-3736.

**Consulate** in **Ho Chi Minh**, as expected:

- 175 Hai Bà Trưng, District 1, ☎ +84 8 3829-2463, fax: +84 8 3827-5845

These first two answers are from Wikivoyage. I went through each page for each city in Vietnam and did not find any others. But you never know ...

The [Wikipedia page on Chinese embassies and consulates around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_China) agrees that these are the only two.

The ["Embassies > Asia"](http://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjb_663304/zwjg_665342/2490_665344/2491_665346/) and ["Consulates General > Asia"](http://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjb_663304/zwjg_665342/2498_665360/2499_665362/) pages on the Chinese Ministry of Foreign website also agrees these are the only two.

Comment: @pnuts: Indeed. Chinese government website: http://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjb_663304/zwjg_665342/2498_665360/2499_665362/t14532.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Searching in French fortunately yields fewer spam results and many forum/blog posts. There is definitely an embassy/consulate in Hanoi were foreigners can get a visa ([here is a very detailed description by someone who did get a visa there a little over a year ago](https://300joursailleurs.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/obtenir-son-visa-pour-la-chine-a-hanoi-et-passer-la-frontiere-depuis-lao-cai-vietnam-vers-hekou-chine/)).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_in_Vietnam) also says something about a consulate-general in Ho Chi Minh City but no details on whether you can get a visa there. The website of the French consulate-general in Ho Chi Minh City [also mentions it, with contact details](http://www.consulfrance-hcm.org/Consulats-generaux-a-Ho-Chi-Minh).